# Recursive foreign key 'on delete cascade'

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS type (
    tid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    uuid VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (tid),
    CONSTRAINT UNQ_0 UNIQUE (uuid),
    CONSTRAINT UNQ_1 UNIQUE (name)
);
CREATE INDEX IDX_type_0 ON type (tid,uuid,name);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS object (
    oid VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    timestamp VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    tid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_tid FOREIGN KEY (tid) REFERENCES type(tid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT UNQ_0 UNIQUE (oid)
);
CREATE INDEX IDX_object_0 ON object (oid,timestamp,tid);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS object_user_owner (
    uid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    oid VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_uid FOREIGN KEY (uid) REFERENCES user(uid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT FK_oid FOREIGN KEY (oid) REFERENCES object(oid) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT UNQ_0 UNIQUE (oid,uid)
);
CREATE INDEX IDX_object_user_owner_0 ON object_user_owner (uid,oid);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    uid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    uuid VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    salt VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    timestamp VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    lastaccess VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (uid),
    CONSTRAINT UNQ_0 UNIQUE (uuid),
    CONSTRAINT UNQ_1 UNIQUE (name)
);
CREATE INDEX IDX_user_0 ON user (uid,uuid,name);
```

The above three sqlite3 tables contain foreign keys. The problem is the deletion of a key in the upper table type. When I try do delete I get 'FOREIGN KEY constraint failed' Error. Deleting a from the lowest table object_user_owner before deleting a type works. I think sqlite does not check any recursive cascade constraints. Does anyone have experienced this too or is anything wrong with my design?

Comment: `Error: no such table: main.user`

Comment: I forgot the user table. 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
 uid INTEGER NOT NULL,
 uuid VARCHAR NOT NULL,
 name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
 password VARCHAR NOT NULL,
 salt VARCHAR NOT NULL,
 timestamp VARCHAR NOT NULL,
 lastaccess VARCHAR NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY (uid),
 CONSTRAINT UNQ_0 UNIQUE (uuid),
 CONSTRAINT UNQ_1 UNIQUE (name)
);
CREATE INDEX IDX_user_0 ON user (uid,uuid,name);

Comment: Works for me. Create an example on [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5).